# генерация access токена

Tags: django-rest-framework

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сгенерировать access-token для созданного ранее приложения? Я использую oauth2 аутентификацию.Мне необходимо иногда вручную генерировать токены. Приложение в админке созданно с параметрами:

```
Client type:  Confidential
Authorization grant type:  Resource owner password-based
```

Как можно созадть access токен зная id этого приложения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы сгенерировать токе для пользователя вручную, потребуется примерно сделующий код:

```
import datetime

from django.conf import settings

from oauth2_provider.models import Application, AccessToken, RefreshToken
from oauth2_provider.settings import oauth2_settings
from oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.tokens import random_token_generator

from smass_cabinet.users.models import User


def get_registration_token(user_id, request):
    """
    Функция генерирующая токен 
    :return:
    """
    registration_app_name = getattr(settings, "REGISTRATION_APP_NAME", "default_app_name")
    expire_seconds = oauth2_settings.user_settings['ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS']
    scopes = oauth2_settings.user_settings['SCOPES']

    live_token_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=expire_seconds)
    user = User.objects.filter(id=user_id).get()
    application = Application.objects.get(name=registration_app_name)
    access_token = AccessToken.objects.create(
        user=user,
        application=application,
        expires=live_token_time,
        token=random_token_generator(request),
        scope=scopes
    )

    refresh_token = RefreshToken.objects.create(
        user=user,
        token=random_token_generator(request),
        access_token=access_token,
        application=application)

    token = {
        'access_token': access_token.token,
        'token_type': 'Bearer',
        'expires_in': expire_seconds,
        'refresh_token': refresh_token.token,
        'scope': scopes}

    return token
```

В settings.py должны быть прописаны настройки:

```
REGISTRATION_APP_NAME = 'app_name'
```

Как видно в качестве аршументов принимает request и id только что созданного пользователя